# Serving multiple static files in nestjs for different locations and prefixes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am currently serving static files for some developer static docs I have created, I am currently using

```
app.useStaticAssets(docsLocation, {
  prefix: "/docs/"
})
```

My question is that I have another directory that I would like to serve, it also has static content, is it possible to serve from different locations and using a different prefix for each location?

Any ideas, this is not covered in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just register static assets multiple times:

```
app.useStaticAssets(docsLocation1, { prefix: "/docs1/" })
app.useStaticAssets(docsLocation2, { prefix: "/docs2/" })
```

Comment: can i use the same prefix ?

Comment: I have the same problem, specifically while using fastify, one of the workaround involves editing fastify.loader.js. However i was thinking can it be done with serve static module and without editing the libraries?