# How to serve 2 SPA's from a NestJS Application

Tags: nestjs

I am using `app.useStaticAssets(ui);` in NestJS app, to server my SPA. The application is running on a browser in kiosk mode.

New kiosk hardware have 2 screens, front, back. It would be easiest if we could create another SPA and serve it on the same NestJS app.

I've looked at the NestJS docs, tried to inspect the source code and searched for related issues, have founds only hints, using res.sendFile (not sure about the assets) or using express under NestJS.

Is there a way to do this in straight NestJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Express as your HTTP Adapter, you could always set multiple static assets and use different prefixes for them

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.useStaticAssets( join(__dirname, '..', 'other'), {prefix: '/other/'});
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

In this case if someone navigates to `localhost:3000` they will get the `index.html` of the `public` folder, but if they navigate to `localhost:3000/other` they will get the `index.html` of the `other` folder.

[Check more out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989258/serving-multiple-static-files-in-nestjs-for-different-locations-and-prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to use the code in Jay's answer, it simply didn't work for me as the routes in my Angular apps 404'd when accessed directly through the server. This is because the built-in `useStaticAssets()` function only serves the files it can find in a given directory, not your Angular or React routes.

I would strongly suggest checking out [@nestjs/serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/serve-static) as it allows you to serve multiple SPAs like so:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join as joinPath } from 'path';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot(
            {
                rootPath: joinPath(__dirname, '..', 'client-admin'),
                serveRoot: '/admin'
            },
            {
                rootPath: joinPath(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
            }
        )

    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Before you can get this working, however, you will need to make sure that your SPAs are configured to be properly mounted at those URLs otherwise the resources (CSS/JS/etc.) will simply 404. For example, if you mount your admin application to `/admin/`, then all the resource file URLs in your `index.html` must be prefixed with `/admin/` as well.

Comment: i could not make it work with fastify. _The decorator sendFile has already been added_ getting this error.